# Cómo mostrar textos largos sobre un PanelSD?

Tags: genexus

Tengo un PanelSD que recibe por parametro un texto largo que debe mostrarlo, y brindar la posibilidad al usuario a recorrerlo todo desplazandose scrolleando.
Primero probé utilizando una variable de tipo Varchar(30000) pero en tiempo de ejecución lo mostraba en una sola linea.
Luego probé utilizar una variable de tipo LogVarChar(2M) pero en tiempo de ejecución si el texto es mayor a dos parrafos Loren Ipsum da error 404. Si el texto es igual a un párrafo Loren Ipsum o menor, funciona perfecto.

Qué tipo de dato debo utilizar para mostrar textos largos ó que propiedad debo tocar para mostrarlos correctamente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuándo y qué texto estás asignando a la variable? Tengo el mismo ejemplo con una variable LongVarChar y se muestra correctamente. ¿Tiene la propiedad Autogrow en truue?

Comment: Dentro del PanelSD origen tenemos un SDT basado en un JSON.
Como la applicacion mobile es OnLine, para pasar el SDT de un panel a otro, primero lo convertimos a string:

dentro del PanelSD_origen coloqué llamado al PanelSDdestino parm(&SDTAttach_OUT.ToJson()) 
 ==== >
PanelSDdestino     parm(&pAttachOut_JSON)

De qué tipo de variable y tamaño deberiamos definir a &pAttachOut_JSON ?
Ya probé con VarChar(30000) pero da el  error que compartí.
Ya probé con LongVarChar(2M) pero da el  mismo error.

Comment: Grabarlo en una &WebSession y el siguiente panel levantarlo al inicio?

Answer (score 2):

El error 404 refiere a que por alguna razón no debe haber encontrado el servicio que trae el texto, desconozco la razón puntual (tal vez no estaba bien el deploy del rest service) pero no esta relacionado al largo del texto.

Deberías usar una variable longvarchar y como dice Guido con autogrow = true.
Fijate también en la Main Table del panel que contiene a la variable, tenga en la propiedad 'Row Style' = 100% (el default es 'pd').

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que existe un SDT (SDTPrueba) con un elemento "LongVarChar" de tipo LongVarChar, en un evento de PanelOrigen que llama a PanelDestino:

```
Event 'LlamarAPanelDestino'
   &SDTPrueba.LongVarChar = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Maloru by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc."  
   SDPanelDestino.Call(&SDTPrueba.ToJson())
EndEvent
```

PanelDestino tiene como parámetro de entrada una variable que es LongVarChar(&SDTPruebaJSON), y en pantalla otra que es LongVarChar(&LongVarChar).
En el evento ClientStart de PanelDestino:

Rules:

```
Parm(in:&SDTPruebaJSON);
```

Events:

```
Event ClientStart
    &SDTPrueba.FromJson(&SDTPruebaJSON)
    &LongVarChar = &SDTPrueba.LongVarChar
Endevent
```

Así, de esta forma, y con la variable en pantalla con AutoGrow = true debería funcionar.

Otra opción sería que PanelDestino en las rules tenga directamente:

Rules:

```
Parm(in:&LongVarChar); //De tipo LongVarChar
```

Y en PanelOrigen pasarle:

```
Event 'LlamarAPanelDestino'
   &SDTPrueba.LongVarChar = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Maloru by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc."  
   SDPanelDestino.Call(&SDTPrueba.LongVarChar)
EndEvent
```